# PDO supports PHP 5.2

Tags: php, pdo, php-5.2

I read that PDO is not supported well (buggy) in php 5.2. I would like to how buggy is PDO in PHP 5.2?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433371/pdo-maturity-in-php-5-2-13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used PDO with PHP 5.2 *(mainly with MySQL databases ; sometimes with Doctrine or Zend Framework, which use PDO underneath)* for years, including on some big/important projects, and have never met any kind of critical bug.

<sub>As a sidenote : PHP 5.2 itself is not quite supported anymore, as [it's reached its end-of-support](http://www.php.net/archive/2010.php#id2010-12-09-1)</sub>